# Display column value as adding "-"

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to show table value as adding "-"

for example we have column value as

```
201602
201732
201853
```

Desired value should be

```
2016-02
2017-32
2018-53
```

in sql

Comment: If the data always has the same format you can combine substring and concatenation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Is this a string or a numeric value?

Comment: Thanks Alvaro for this. I will take care in future

Comment: This is numeric..but i can change to string as well

Answer (score 3):

```
select substr(col,1,4)||'-'||substr(col,5) from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column type is numeric, you can use the MOD operator.

the query would be:

```
select int(col/100)||'-'||mod(col,100) from my_table
```

Comment: "INT": invalid id

Comment: @user1213199 - use `trunc()` instead of `int()`. The mod'd value needs to be zero-padded though, or the first value is shown as `2016-2`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression, assuming the value is always exactly six digits, splitting the value with a four-digit and two-digit pattern and using back references to reconstruct it:

```
with mytable (value) as (
  select 201602 from dual
  union all select 201732 from dual
  union all select 201853 from dual
)
select value, regexp_replace(value, '(\d{4})(\d{2})', '\1-\2') as new_value
from mytable;

     VALUE NEW_VALUE                     
---------- ------------------------------
    201602 2016-02                       
    201732 2017-32                       
    201853 2018-53
```

Using substr may be more efficient with a lot of data though. You are implicitly converting the number to a string with both; doing it explicitly isn't really necessary but might be desirable for clarity.

If you can have longer values, this would always put the dash after the fourth character, so 1234567 would be shown as 1234-567. If you wanted the last two digits to always be separated instead you can use pattern `'(\d{4})(\d{2})$'` instead, with a `$` anchor; and to cope with shorter values you can omit the size from the first grouping:

```
with mytable (value) as (
  select 201602 from dual
  union all select 201732 from dual
  union all select 201853 from dual
  union all select 12 from dual
  union all select 123 from dual
  union all select 1234 from dual
  union all select 1234567 from dual
)
select value, regexp_replace(value, '(\d+)(\d{2})$', '\1-\2') as new_value
from mytable;

     VALUE NEW_VALUE                     
---------- ------------------------------
    201602 2016-02                       
    201732 2017-32                       
    201853 2018-53                       
        12 12                            
       123 1-23                          
      1234 12-34                         
   1234567 12345-67
```

Answer (score 0):

use operator `' || '` this concat your select;

example :

`SELECT 'TEST' || '-' || 'MY' || '-' || 'QUERY' FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 0):

> CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] )

see more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh231515.aspx